# Sequelize Response on non-existant record

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Recently I figured that `article` is null when I query for a non-existent id. Is it supposed to be like that or will I get a response / error response from the database / sequelize?

```
[err, article] = await to(
    Articles.findById(body.articleId)
  );
  if (err) return ReE(req, res, err, 422);
return ReS(req, res, article, 200);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The query will look for something u ask, it ether finds something or nothing=Null
Its supposed to do that